# Test the return value of a template tag

Tags: django

There's a boolean variable defined in `settings.py` that I'd like to make visible in my templates, so that I can control whether a part of the template is shown.

I've thought of creating a template tag to expose the value to the template:

```
@register.simple_tag
def show_something():
    return settings.SHOW_SOMETHING
```

... which I would use in the template like this:

```
{% if show_something %}
    Show it
{% endif %}
```

... but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Also tried outputting the value, and this displays it as I expected:

```
{% show_something %}
```

Any idea if using a template tag is possible for what I need, or if there's a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a template context processor might be better suited for this. Put a `context_processors.py` file in your project

#### context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings

def some_setting(request):
    # Or some other logic here instead of always returning it
    return {
        'some_setting': settings.SOME_SETTING
    }
```

#### settings.py

```
SOME_SETTING = False

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    'path.to.context_processors.some_setting'
)
```

and in your templates you can now access the variable with `{{ some_setting }}` or use it in an `if` statement like `{% if some_setting %}Show this{% endif %}`